# whats the function of height: auto here?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to determine what `height:auto;` is doing here.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

This code is from the following link: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-principles/make-an-image-responsive

Answer (score 0):

`height: auto;` is used for letting browser adjust the height of the image with respect to aspect ratio of image.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the article: "The height property of auto keeps the original aspect ratio of the image."

The image will keep the width and height ratio of the original image, resizing for the container.

For example:

- The image is 500px width x 250px height
- The aspect ratio is 2 (500/250)
- The container has max-width 200px
- You will obtain an image with width 200px and height 100px

Also note that if the original image is smaller than the container, it will not fit it completely and just display the orginal image.

Comment: why is max-width set to 100% then? shouldnt it be set to auto too?

Comment: You set max-width 100% to make your image responsive. The width of the image will be either smaller than the container (or screen) if the original image is smaller, or the maximum width will be the container. And in any case, the aspect ratio will be preserved thanks to height auto. If you don't set the max width, it will be displayed following the original dimension of the image (and possibly go off screen!)